# Config command for -l argument in scp?

Tags: ssh, rsync, scp

Is there a command in the `$HOME/.ssh/config` file that maps to `scp`'s `-l` argument to limit the transfer rate?

My actual goal is to be able to use `rsync` to copy files via SSH with a transfer rate limit.  `rsync` does not have (AFAIK) a `-l` argument, so I would need to rely on that command via the config file.

Comment: Doesn't `rsync` have a `--bwlimit=RATE` option?

Comment: Facepalm !!!  :‒)  Yes, it does, as `rsync --help` clearly shows!

Comment: @steeldriver ‒ if you write the above as an answer, maybe add the clarification that `--bwlimit` accepts the rate in kbytes per second, as opposed to `scp` in kbits per second